# Magmi Column Mapper error

Tags: magento, magmi

I am successfully using Magmi for a while now, recently when trying for the first time to update Stock (**qty** field) in Magento 1.8 I came across an issue and haven't been able to resolve... not sure what I am missing here...

Here's the scenario:

I recieve a .CSV with ONE column of data (no header), the rows are sku numbers:

```
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
```

these skus are supposed to be the OOS update... and so I setup MAGMI to:

> Assign a header called "sku" for the ONLY existing column:
>
> > On Column mapper v0.0.3
> >      - Mapped columns list = A
> >      - New name for col A = sku
>
> Add 2 more columns (qty and is_in_stock) both with values = 0
>
> > On Value Replacer v0.0.8a
> >      - Replaced attributes = qty,is_in_stock
> >      - New value for qty = 0
> >      - New value for is_in_stock = 0
>
> Other general settings for the local CSV are
>
> > - CSV separator: (,) CSV Enclosure: (")
> > - [checked] Headerless CSV (Use Column Mapper Plugin to set processable column names)

my hope is to have the CSV looking like this before MAGMI runs the update:

```
sku qty is_in_stock
0001    0   0
0002    0   0
0003    0   0
0004    0   0
```

And here's the errors I see when I run the update:

```
No sku info found for record #1
No sku info found for record #2
No sku info found for record #3
No sku info found for record #4
No sku info found for record #5
No sku info found for record #6
No sku info found for record #7
```

```
Skus imported KO:7/7
```

When I manually build the CSV with the headers and rows the Upload works correctly. What am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Import - CSV datasource Documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Import_-_CSV_datasource), it says the following for headerless CSVs:

> Headerless CSV : check this when CSV has no column names. the columns
>   will be automatically named **col1,.....,colN**.

The columns are incremented *numerically*, not alphabetically.

So you want to use **col1** instead of **col A** in the mapping field.

Your configuration should look like this:
[image]